# $\mathcal{F}_\tau$-measurability of stopping time

Tags: stopping-times, measurable-functions

When proving that a stopping time $\tau$ is $\mathcal{F}_\tau$-measurable it suffices to show that $\{ \tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_\tau$ in my opinion which is not very difficult. My question is, why showing $\{ \tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_\tau$ is enough.

Is it because of
\begin{equation}
\{ \tau = t \} = \{\tau \leq t\} \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \{\tau > t + 1/n\}
\end{equation}
and $ \{ \tau < t \} = \{ \tau \leq t \} - \{\tau = t\}$? Is this reasoning ok? Or is there a very obvious and shorter argument? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the  definition of $\mathcal F_\tau$? Please state it. Also state explicitly what you must prove in order to show that a random variable $X$ is $\mathcal F_\tau$ measurable. This will help us understand how familiar you are with the definitions.

Comment: Are you sure you mean $\mathcal F_\tau$ measurable, or do you mean $\mathcal F_t$ measurable?

Comment: Yes, I really want to prove that $\tau$ is $\mathcal{F}_\tau$-measurable where $\mathcal{F}_\tau = \{ A : \{ \{\tau \leq t \} \cap A \in \mathcal{F}_t\}$. The question is why it is enough to show $\{\tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_\tau$ only and why the other cases follow from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is not correct. By definition $\{\tau \leq t\}\in \mathcal F_{\tau}$ means $\{\tau \leq t\} \cap \{\tau \leq s\}\in \mathcal F_s$ for each  $s$. For this note that $\{\tau \leq t\} \cap \{\tau \leq s\}=\{\tau \leq t\wedge s\} \in \mathcal F_{t\wedge s} \subset \mathcal F_s$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question was actually why it is enough to show $\{ \tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_\tau $ and why I do not have to show $\{ \tau = t\}$ etc.

Comment: @BenC. I have just applied the definition of  set belonging to $\mathcal F_{\tau}$.

Comment: Yes, I know. But my question is: Why is it enough to show $\{\tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_\tau$ for $\tau$ to be $\mathcal{F}_\tau$-measurable? What about the other cases, $\{\tau = t\}$  and $\{ \tau < t\}$? Sorry for not making my question clear enough.

Comment: To show that $\tau$ is meaurable w.r.t. some sigma algebra $\mathcal G$ it is enough to show that $\{\tau \leq a\} \in \mathcal G$ for every real number $a$. This comes from the fact that  intervals of the type $(-\infty ,a]$ generate the Borel sigma algebra of the real line. @BenC.

Comment: Thank you! That kind of concise argument was what I was looking for. I again apologize for the unclear statement of my question.